# Struct param not found

Tags: struct, error

I´m trying to call a function insertOrigin inside a struct and then call other function getOrigin to return that values. But VS Code get a error

```
pragma solidity ^ "0.4.24";

contract Origin {

struct OriginInfo
{
    string airportName;
    uint32 checkInTime; //In timestamp
    uint8 bagWeight;
    address clientAddress;
    bool itsHere;
}

function insertOrigin(string _airportName, uint32 _checkInTime, uint8 _bagWeight, bool _itsHere) external
{
    /*OriginInfo[] originInfoArray;
    originInfoArray.length++;

    originInfoArray[originInfoArray.length-1].airportName = _airportName;
    originInfoArray[originInfoArray.length-1].checkInTime = _checkInTime;
    originInfoArray[originInfoArray.length-1].bagWeight = _bagWeight;
    originInfoArray[originInfoArray.length-1].clientAddress = _clientAddress;
    originInfoArray[originInfoArray.length-1].itsHere = _itsHere;*/


    OriginInfo(_airportName, _checkInTime, _bagWeight, msg.sender, true);
    getOrigin();
}

function getOrigin() private constant returns (string, uint32, uint8, address, bool) 
{
    return (OriginInfo.airportName, 
    OriginInfo.checkInTime, 
    OriginInfo.bagWeight, 
    OriginInfo.clientAddress, 
    OriginInfo.itsHere);
}
}
```

[image]

Any idea?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're not querying an instance of `OriginInfo`, but the struct declaration itself. You have to use a mapping in order to achieve what you want:

```
pragma solidity ^ "0.4.24";

contract Origin {

    struct OriginInfo
    {
        string airportName;
        uint32 checkInTime; //In timestamp
        uint8 bagWeight;
        address clientAddress;
        bool itsHere;
    }
    mapping (uint256 => OriginInfo) origins;
    uint256 public originNonce;

    constructor() public {
        originNonce = 1;
    }

    function insertOrigin(string _airportName, uint32 _checkInTime, uint8 _bagWeight, bool _itsHere) 
        external 
    {
        origins[originNonce] = OriginInfo(_airportName, _checkInTime, _bagWeight, msg.sender, true);
        originNonce += 1;
    }

    function getOrigin(uint256 _originId) 
        private 
        constant 
        returns (string, uint32, uint8, address, bool) 
    {
        OriginInfo memory origin = origins[_originId];
        return (
            origin.airportName,
            origin.checkInTime, 
            origin.bagWeight, 
            origin.clientAddress, 
            origin.itsHere
        );
    }
}
```